# Question on probability distribution

Tags: probability-theory

If a random variable has a moment generation function $$M(t) = a + (1-a) \, e^t$$  with   $ 0 < a < 1$

a) Determine the Distribution of $X$

b) Show that the moment of r-class of $X$ is equal to $E[X^r] = 1-a$ , for $1,2,\ldots$

**Edit:**

So this is my best best approach till now; We know that $$M_x(t) = \mathbb{E} \left[e^{tx} \right] = \int_{ -\infty}^{+\infty}  e^{t x} f(x) dx $$

Also I know that $M_x(t=0)=1$.

So, if I could find $f(x)$, I could easily then find $F(x)$ (distribution).

The problem is that I am doing cyrcles all over my papers .

Should I find $\text{Var}(X)$? thats easy... and then try from this?

Can't think of anything else.

Comment: This is not a "do my homework for me" site. Show us what you've tried and where are you stuck. And dont' copy the exercise statement, as if given orders.  Read http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask
http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-to-ask-a-homework-question

Comment: @ leonbloy never said that this is a "do my homework" site ...

Comment: Back on the problem , it seems that the Var(X) equals to zero ... also, all the derivatives of Mx(t) are all equal .

Comment: I edited the math, check if all is ok.

Comment: "Var(X) equals to zero " Why?

Comment: yeah right wrong calculation

Answer (score 2):

**HINT** Think of discrete random variables.

Move your mouse over the gray area below for another hint.

> **HINT** Bernoulli random variable.

Move your mouse over the gray area below for the complete answer.

> $M(t) = a + (1-a) \exp(t)$ corresponds to a bernoulli random variable $X$ where
>  $$X = \begin{cases} 0 & \text{ with probability }a\\ 1 & \text{ with probability }1-a \end{cases}$$
>  Hence, $$\mathbb{E}(X^r) = 0^r \times a + 1^r \times (1-a) = (1-a)$$

Answer (score 1):

You formula for the MGF is ok; now, in the particular case  when the variable has a discrete probability function (its density is a sum of Dirac deltas), say $p_k = P(X=k) $, the integral turns into a sum:

$$M_x(t) = \sum_{k}  p_k e^{t k} $$

Then, by inspection , you can guess your density: it's the sum of just two exponentials (one with $k=0$)

$$M_x(t) = p_0 e^{0t} + p_1 e^{1 t} = p_0 + p_1 e^t = a + (1-a) \, e^t  $$

so it's a Bernoulli with $p=1-a$  Can you go on from here?

Comment: oh my god  i see.... thanks for your answers.. Bernoulli .. voila! and its discrete of course... i thought it was continouus.. due to the stupid a, i guess =/  Need sleep asap.